# How to resolve chown: invalid user while starting apache server?

Tags: linux, apache, lamp

I am trying to start apache2 services by running-

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

But it is resulting in-

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I tried-

```
sudo systemctl status apache2.service
```

and it's showing-

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-08 11:17:18 IST; 7min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 30529 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 08 11:17:18 dk systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 08 11:17:18 dk apachectl[30535]: chown: invalid user: 'dk'
Dec 08 11:17:18 dk systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 08 11:17:18 dk systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 08 11:17:18 dk systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I am assuming the problem is with invalid user: dk. How can i resolve this?
Also I recently removed one user account which already had LAMP stack installed. Is that the reason why it's showing invalid user?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks for the advice. I will try asking the question in those sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new systems, e.g. ubuntu 20 * LTS, the configuration file is `/etc/apache2/envvars`

look for APACHE_RUN_USER and APACHE_RUN_GROUP.

Comment: Yes, the RUN_USER and RUN_GROUP is set to dk. Should i change it to www-data

Comment: I changed it to www-data and it's working now. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Cool - it's great that I could help

Answer (score 0):

You must see in the file:
`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
or
 `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

- what is the entered user and what group

normally it is:

```
User www-data
Group www-data
```

or maybe in your case it is "dk"

in addition, you may have specified in the server file that the site location is in a directory owned by "dk".

Check the server configuration with the command:

```
apachectl configtest
```

or

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

Comment: `apachectl configtest` returns `chown: invalid user: 'dk'`